# Is it ok to use bit-fields in embedded system firmware?

Tags: c, embedded

I see that some embedded system Firmware books/articles suggest not to use C's structure bit field as it isn't portable. I know that the order and padding is implementation defined, but is it always not portable to use bit fields?
I mean, if for example I defined a configuration structure for a 8-bit microcontroller driver like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  int channel_name :3 ; /*7 possible channels*/
  int Enable :1 ;  /*if 1 enable,otherwise disable*/
  int Mode;
} conf_t
```

I don't understand how can the implementation defined behavior raise a portability issue in such a case, can anyone explain?

Comment: does probability matter if you lets say define bits in the hardware register? are you going to run this program on the IBM mainframe?

Comment: The assertion is debatable. A point of fact is that the handling is **compiler dependent**, and some assumption on memory allocation, for embedded systems, could be not compliant changing the compiler (not portable). Unless you have strict requirements for structure memory layout you can use it in general. A more portable option is the use of masking and shifting techniques to extract bit limited data out of larger data type.

Comment: @Frankie_C number of compilers available for uC programming is relatively small and **all** major implement the bitfields the same way (gcc, Keil, IAR, GHS, MPLAB)

Comment: @Frankie_C 8 bits micros have even less available options

Comment: Portability doesn't matter if you're never going to port the program.

Comment: @P__J__ I thought I was agreeing with you...

Comment: @SteveFriedl It's naive to think you'll never have to port the program. Quite a few programs will have to get ported to a different compiler at some point, even if the hardware stays the same. Especially true for embedded systems. In addition, it is quite nice to be able to re-use already written code in new projects.

Comment: @P__J__ I can mention at least 10 more. And then different hardware ports of all those compilers. They do not implement padding, endianess or even bit order the same. They are all quite different with how they handle bit padding when you mix different types in the same struct.

Comment: @Lundin 10 more  for the same architecture? Can you list them for me please. For AVR8 and ARM-Cortex (except those 5 I have listed).

Comment: @P__J__ Nobody said same architecture, though for ARM Cortex specifically you also have Tasking, Wind River, Cosmic, and probably a bunch that I'm not aware of. There's something called mikroC etc.

Comment: @P__J__: CodeWarrior, DIAB, Cosmic, Tasking, clang, SDCC, TI compilers for DSPs, VisualDSP or whatever Analog Devices calls them now. And I don't know, why you just mention AVR8 and ARM-Cortex, there are much more controllers/architectures there than AVR and ARM. And in our SoCs, we sometimes have 3..4 different processing cores inside, like Cortex-M4, Cortex-R5F and C66x DSP, or e200z4 and e200z7, or Cortex-M7 + Cortex-A53 + Tensilica BBE32. Now, good luch exchanging data between these cores, if you are using bitfields and such things impacting portability and data exchange.

Comment: @SteveFriedl *Portability doesn't matter if you're never going to port the program.* And then a new, cheaper, better-performing microcontroller from another source becomes available and all your assumptions about not needing portability get flushed down the nearest toilet.

Comment: @Lundin - The importance of portability depends on the class of software; if you're coding to the hardware it's often worth little more than a head-fake nod to portability. Back in the late eighties, I ported my commercial fax software to something like 50 (!) UNIX platforms, so it was a big hairy deal, but when I'm writing for Arduino, I do not give one iota of thought to it (and I would say an 8-bit micro is in the same category). But it's fair to at least be aware that you're *intentionally* making that kind of decision rather than be non-portable by accident.

Comment: @SteveFriedl Another aspect: I've written plenty of simulators and test cases for my MCU programs on a 64 bit PC. For example at one point I designed a radio spectrum allocation algorithm and needed a graphical simulator to visualize and debug the algorithm. The target platform was a 8 bit MCU but I ran all tests on 64 bit x86. To do the same by hacking together some LCD graphics library + fixing hardware for it would have been way more time consuming than writing portable code and then hack together a simple Windows app in a RAD tool.

Comment: @Lundin - Sure, and I think this pretty much reinforces my point that the most useful portability skill is *knowledge*, so you can make a proper tradeoff of cost/benefit. Some are free (`time_t` instead of `long` or whatever, something that bit me badly some decades ago - shame on me), while others require much more considered scaffolding. Sometimes it's worth the effort, and with experience this comes easier, but sometimes it's just not worth it at all.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some of the portability issues that are likely to occur:

- Byte padding issues. What will be the size of this struct?
- Endianess and bit order issues caused by it. Will `channel_name` get allocated in the 3 MSB or the 3 LSB?
- Different behavior from different compilers when you declare an `int` bitfield of size 1. What goes into that bit, the sign bit or data? In a bitfield (and only there), compilers may treat `int` either as signed or unsigned, and in case of signed, they may behave differently in regards of the sign bit.
- Behavior in terms of bit/byte padding upon mixing different types in the same bitfield.

Then there's a bunch of other things that are poorly-defined as well, but less likely to cause actual problems in reality.

Comment: `Will channel_name get allocated in the 3 MSB or the 3 LSB?` read your compiler documentation. But all listed by you compilers behave exactly the same

Comment: @Lundin This struct will be just passed by pointer to the driver's functions to set the proper configuretion, so:
(1) why does the size matter? i think that in worst case it will be lesser than that struct without bit-fileds, right?
(2) if i am just accessing the members like this ```  if(conf_t->channel_name == 2) {//do something}``` , will the order of allocation in the int boundary matter?
(3) will adding an extra bit and ignoring it solve the sign problem?
(4) i don't really understand what do you mean by "mixing different types in the same bitfield".

Comment: @AhmedAbdalrahiem Please note that my answer is general. Most problems with bit-fields only occur when you actually rely on their binary representation. If you don't, then they aren't as problematic, but if you don't then what's the whole point of using bit-fields to begin with? 1) The size won't matter unless you intend for the bit-field to be the binary representation of something such as a hardware register or data protocol. 2) In that specific case it doesn't matter. 3) Why not use unsigned types instead? 4) For example `{ char x : 1;  int x : 1; }`.

Comment: @Lundin The only reason that makes me thinking of bit fields(in the special case i mentioned) is just to decrease the overall size of the struct, i mean why to use a 8 bit data type while the max value that wil be asigned to the struct member is just from zero to 4 !

Answer (score 1):

1. Device registers often have side effects, for example, reading a status register might clear a detected conditions.  You have no way of controlling how many accesses the compiler might make in a given expression.  Reflexively, when you update a structure with bitfields, the compiler is free to make multiple writes to the storage location, which could have a dramatic effect.
2. Even if you have sorted out *your compiler* what advantage are you gaining with this?  Does it really make the code more readable, or just shorter?  Often the latter implies the former, but there are limits.
3. The numbering of bits in a bitfield normally follows the byte ordering of the machine; so { int x:1; }  would be the least significant bit on an intel machine, but the most significant bit on a motorola machine.  In contrast (1 << 0) is the least significant bit on all machines.  [ I once had to go through an 8kloc video capture driver stuffed with bitfields to move it to another architecture ].
4. The casual notion that *p is sufficient to read a register with an appropriate bus protocol is a long dead notion, and should stay there.  x = io_readb(device) is inherently self documenting; or even better : if (io_readb(device, &x) != 0) { panic("device failed"); }.